# Animator not animating a runtime instantiated child (UNITY)

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have a GameObject representing a room. As childs of this room I have 3 characters. Room has an animator component that control the synchronized animation of all characters.

The problem is I have another character that is instantiate from a prefab at runtime and this doesn't animate.

I tried several things:

```
//NOT WORKING
IEnumerator Start()
{
    room.SetBool("e8", true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
    ...
}

//NOT WORKING
IEnumerator Start()
{
    room.Rebind();
    room.SetBool("e8", true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
    ...
}

//WORKING
IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    room.Rebind();
    room.SetBool("e8", true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
    ...

}
```

The last try is working but the character looks stopped for an instant and suddenly jumps to the animation. I want the character animating from the beginning like the other characters.

My animator:
[image]

Comment: your first two `Start` methods are a compile time error because a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)(IEnumerator) always has to include at least one `yield` operation. If you don't necessarily need a coroutine its better to run `Start` as void, which doesn't require you to yield to the end of the frame.

Comment: @remy is only a fragment of my code. After that I have a waitforseconds(6) but it's not important for my specific problem and for that I didn't include it. I edit my question.

Comment: @Juan Lopez, can you attach screenshot with your animator? Because it always depends on how you did your animator

Answer (score 0):

Simple solving

With current animator settings, this behavior is normal. You need to change your current animator using Any State section because when you use changing state from other states, Animation needs time to change your states. And for start Animator needs time for initializing, but if you will use Any State this will work.

Try doing something like this:

[image: Animator settings]

Entry different states

Either you can use what official documentation offers to you:

> You can then add additional transitions from the Entry node to other states, to control whether the state machine should begin in a different state.

https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/Manual/StateMachineTransitions.html

For example:

[image]